# Changing terminal in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I set up git in the IntelliJ terminal and now I'm asking me how I can go back to the standard terminal.

I didn't find the option. Do you know where it is?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Settings dialog has a handy search field, type Terminal inside and you'll find all the related options:

[image: teminal]

Comment: Thank you. Would be that bin/bash on the Mac OS?

Comment: Yes, you can use `/bin/bash` on Mac.

Comment: If anyone needs: git bash in windows (default) location: `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe`

Comment: why wont the commands work like git, mvn in intellij terminal?

Comment: @Sushilzzz they work if they are in PATH environment visible to the IDE process